# Is it normal to see "Via", "X-Cache" headers in HTTP connections to my app?

Tags: http, http-headers, signalr, squid, http-caching

I was having some problems with SignalR connection to my Azure app, and when I was examining the errored requests/responses, I've seen some unusual headers that I haven't seen before:

```
Via = "1.0 94.102.75.40 (squid/3.1.23)";
"X-Cache" = "MISS from 94.102.75.40";
"X-Cache-Lookup" = "MISS from 94.102.75.40:3128";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
```

When I traceroute that IP address, I get:

```
traceroute to 94.102.75.40 (94.102.75.40), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  94.102.75.40 (94.102.75.40)  8.712 ms  8.826 ms  10.302 ms
```

Is something caching my requests? If yes, how can I prevent that behavior?

Comment: These headers are not abnormal. What exactly are you trying to fix and or prevent?

Comment: @pvg I have connection/immediate disconnection issues to my SignalR backend from my iOS app, I'm just not sure if these headers may be related to the issue. Maybe they are completely irrelevant, but I don't know.

Comment: The headers suggest that the connections are coming through a caching proxy, that's all. Whether that breaks your app or not, not really possible to tell.

Comment: @pvg I see. So it indicates a cache miss, and it's not a cached response, right?

Comment: These are headers on a request, right? It seems to say it's performing the request because it thinks it doesn't have cached content for it. That doesn't mean it doesn't cache your stuff, ever.

Comment: @pvg i see.. I though the same too but I wasn't sure. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?